# Login / signup controls on my Wordpress blog unclear

Tags: wordpress

I am really new to Wordpress and I seem to have broken things.

My blog is here:

blog.publictalksoftware.co.uk

See this post:

http://blog.publictalksoftware.co.uk/2017/08/22/including-the-page-numbers-from-the-school-book-on-the-worksheet/

At the very bottom is this:

[image: Login]

1. That "logged in" text is not very clear that it is a hyperlink. Can that be changed in any way?
2. If the user goes to blog.publictalksoftware.co.uk I see no where that they can sign up to Wordpress and thus have access to commenting on the blog.

This is all new to me (please advise).

The newsletter form is for Mailchimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under 'Theme Options' you should see a lot of style options for your site. One of these will reference link colors. This is somewhat theme dependant so it is hard to show you, but the links on my web page are styled under the 'Body' section of 'Theme Options' -> 'Customize Theme'

Specifically, link colors are set here:
[Link Styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sjqV.png)

If no options like this appear in your theme, you will need to resort to custom CSS. Hopefully your theme has a section for adding custom CSS somewhere. If not there are WordPress add-ons available to do this. The link you are looking at has no class or id associated with it, so you will need to style the anchor tag.

As an example adding this custom css would turn all the links with no more specific styling on your webpage red:

```
a {
color: #f00;
}
```

Here is what that would look like:
[Link modified to be red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paDkO.png)